# Alias a protocol to a url

Tags: alias, protocol

I currently work in an organisation which is mostly Windows users but there are some including myself using Linux here.

We have a shared storage drive which we use for sharing files between us and I very often receive emails with a link to a file in the shared storage. Most of these links are sent from windows users and so have a link like `Z:\storage\file` and so when using windows it is easy to copy into a browser or explorer window or just click a hyperlink. However on linux we can access it using the intranet e.g `http://intranet/storage/file` or by a mounted folder `/media/storage/file`.

I'm trying to set up a way to alias `Z:\storage\` to `http://intranet/storage/` or `file:///media/storage/` so when I click a windows link it opens the file instead of having to copy part of the link and type part of the Linux location. Currently I get the error saying

> Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol
>   (z) isn't associated with any program

which is to be expected when I click one of the windows links.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a protocol handler to the `Z` protocol and then in your shell script change the path to as you need it and open using nautilus (or w/e)? Here is a post from someone who details his efforts of doing something similar [Using a custom protocol handler in Firefox to run a shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161553/using-a-custom-protocol-handler-in-firefox-to-run-a-shell-script).